# "Execute does not exist" when writing Postgres Function

Tags: sql, postgresql, function

I'm working on a function, which is supposed to look up for some tables if there was written at least one entry yesterday. In any case, TRUE or FALSE should be written into another table:

```
  CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION SANDBOX.MY_FUNCTION(MY_TABLE regclass, DATE_DIFF INTEGER)
    RETURNS void AS $$
 DECLARE
RESULT BOOLEAN;
 BEGIN
      RESULT :=
      EXECUTE 'EXISTS
      (SELECT DATE FROM ' || MY_TABLE ||
       ' WHERE DATE = CURRENT_DATE -DATE_DIFF
       LIMIT 1)';
      INSERT INTO SANDBOX.UPDATED_TODAY VALUES (MY_TABLE, CURRENT_DATE, RESULT);
    END;
    $$ LANGUAGE plpgsql;
```

However, I'm getting

```
[42704]ERROR: type "execute does not exist"
```

This is my function call:

```
SELECT SANDBOX.MY_FUNCTION('datawarehouse_a.table_2', 1);
```

Can anybody help?
Thanks in advance! :-)

If you're courious about the 2nd parameter: For some tables, I'm looking if there was an entry not yesterday, but 2 days ago.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`EXECUTE` does not return a result like that. You need to EXECUTE INTO to get the result into a variable:

```
DO $$
DECLARE
        result BOOLEAN;
BEGIN
        EXECUTE 'SELECT EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM generate_series(1, 10))'
        INTO result;

        RAISE NOTICE '%', result;
END $$
```

Prints: `NOTICE:  t`